# Matrix Representation of Softmax Derivatives in Backpropagation

Tags: derivative, softmax

I have a simple multilayer fully connected neural network for classification. At the last layer I have used softmax activation function. So I have to propagate the error through the softmax layer. Suppose, I have 3 `softmax units` at the output layer. Input to these 3 logits can be described by the vector
 $z =\begin{pmatrix}z1\\z2\\z3\end{pmatrix}$. Now let's say those 3 logits output $y = \begin{pmatrix}y1\\y2\\y3\end{pmatrix}$. Now I want to calculate $
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$. Which is simply: $ $ $$\begin{equation} \\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial z} softmax(z)
\end{equation}
$$
I know the derivatives of the softmax function are really $y(\delta_{ij}-y)$. Here $\delta$ is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). I can actually break down this expression and write down into two matrices( **maybe here I am going wrong**):
 $$\texttt{matrix_a} =\begin{bmatrix}y1(1-y) & 0 & 0 \\0 & y2(1-y2) & 0\\0 &0 & y3(1-y3)\end{bmatrix}$$ and 
$$\texttt{matrix_b} =\begin{bmatrix}0 & -y1y2 & -y1y3 \\-y1y2 & 0 & -y2y3\\-y1y3 &-y2y3 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$. 
So finally, then I add these matrices to get the following matrix:
$$\texttt{matrix_c} =\begin{bmatrix}y1(1-y1) & -y1y2 & -y1y3 \\-y1y2 & y2(1-y2) & -y2y3\\-y1y3 &-y2y3 & y3(1-y3)\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Now if I take the sum over the rows I should get the column matrix of $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$. So the final column matrix containing the derivatives for $z$ is:
$$\texttt{matrix} =\begin{pmatrix}y1(1-y1)-y1y2-y1y3 \\-y1y2+y2(1-y2)-y2y3\\-y1y3-y2y3+y3(1-y3)\end{pmatrix}$$
But this is definitely wrong as $y1+y2+y3 = 1.0$ so I get the derivative for each of the softmax unit 0. Can you please tell me where I am doing it wrong and how I can make it correct? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of softmax and squared error](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153285/derivative-of-softmax-and-squared-error)

Comment: (which is answered by Bengio ... :-O )

Comment: This is not duplicate. I want to find the matrix of sofmax derivatives.

Comment: Here's an article giving a vectorised proof of the formulas of back propagation.
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-10-line-proof-of-back-propagation-5a2cad1032c4 It starts with the differentiation of cross entropy and goes all the way to its partial derivates with respect to the weights. The plus here is that **not so many summations and subscripts are used**, and you can clearly see where the transpose and the order of matrix multiplication come from. Moreover, the matrix format is kept in all of the steps of the proof, so that you don't jump to scalar form and loose the respect of the dimensi

Answer (score 2):

The final `matrix` is already a matrix of derivatives $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$. Every element $i, j$ of the matrix correspond to the single derivative of form $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial z_j}$.

One usually expects to compute gradients for the backpropagation algorithm but those can be computed only for scalars. In this case the $y$ is a vector hence we stack the gradients of it's components (a single component of $y$ vector is a scalar) forming a Jacobian matrix:

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial y_3}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_1} &  \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_2} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_3} \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_1} &  \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_2} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_3} \\
\frac{\partial y_3}{\partial z_1} &  \frac{\partial y_3}{\partial z_2} & \frac{\partial y_3}{\partial z_3}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}y_1(1-y_1) & -y_1y_2 & -y_1y_3 \\-y_1y_2 & y_2(1-y_2) & -y_2y_3\\-y_1y_3 &-y_2y_3 & y_3(1-y_3)\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note however that in backpropagation we would usually compute the gradient of some loss function $L$. Since it is a scalar we can compute it's gradient wrt. $z$:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}
$$

The component $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$ is a gradient (i.e. vector) which should be computed in the previous step of the backpropagation and depends on the actual loss function form (e.g. cross-entropy or MSE). The second component is the matrix shown above. By multiplying the vector $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$ by the matrix $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ we get another vector $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ which is suitable for another backpropagation step.

Note that the formula for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}$ might be a little difficult to derive in the vectorized form as shown above. It should be easier to start by computing the derivatives for single elements and vectorizing the equation later:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_j} = \sum_i \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_i} \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial z_j}
$$

The above equation for a single element of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}$ is equivalent to the vectorized form above. One could convince himself/herself by  comparing this equation to the way the vector-matrix multiplication works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a vector from the softmax derivative; I fell in the same mistake too. You can leave it in matrix form. Consider you have: $ y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} $ as your network prediction and have $ t_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} $ as the desired target. With squared error as loss function you're looking at:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{i}} * \frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial z_{i}} $$

where $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial y_{i}} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} $ and $
\frac{\partial y_{i}}{\partial z_{i}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $. Now in order to get $ \delta_{i} $ you need to multiply those two derivatives together which gives you: $ \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} = \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n} $ and you can continue your standard backpropagation.